# Where store text files?

Tags: storage, logfiles

On many forums, I need to show some log files or any text file in general (configuration, source code,...).
Usually this messages are quite long and the post is hard to read if there's several big code blocks...

Where can I store it on a different website such as imageshack for the pictures. I don't want to use websites such as megaupload or rapidshare as there is usually a time limitation and a captcha and need to wait with the free account (so 1 minut needed to just open a simple text file).

I don't have any personal website where I could store it and anyway even if I had one I'm not sure it's really a good idea as I don't know how long I'll keep it...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) or another pastebin site sounds like it fits your needs. My personal preference is for [Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/).

Comment: yeah that's about what I'm looking for
Thank you. I'll try Lodge It (http://paste.pocoo.org/) which is kind of really easy

Answer (score 0):

How about [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)? Or maybe [Google Code](http://code.google.com)?

Comment: good for the source code but maybe not easy enough for the log files
I need something easy and fast to both consult and post

Answer (score 0):

[Gist](http://gist.github.com/) is really nice too, you can embed the file and others can use git to pull it.